# 'User' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to create a registration form. Everything works fine until I try to raise a validation error in case email already exists. It says, `'User' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'`

Here's what I did,

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            mail = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
                raise new_form.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
            else:
                new_form.save()
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
```

How can we fix that?

Comment: Can you post your imports in views.py  and forms.py

Comment: @VipinMohan Sir, I'm importing it as `from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError`. Also, If I remove this ValidationError line from View, everything starts working fine!

Comment: try importing forms.ValidationError, not core.exceptions.ValidationError

Answer (score 0):

try to add below method to your form

```
from django import forms
from .models import User

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

   # ..............
   # ..............

   def clean(self):
      mail = form.cleaned_data['email']
      if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
          raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
      return self.cleaned_data
```

change the code in `views.py`

```
if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
            raise new_form.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
        else:
            new_form.save()
```

to

```
new_form.save()
```

Comment: Sir, again it's raising a similar error, `'RegistrationForm' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'`

Comment: Sir, now it's raising an error `'User' object has no attribute 'ValidationError'`

Comment: What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

When validating a form error, you should import validationError from django.forms and not django.core.exceptions

try :

```
from django.forms import ValidationError
```

Comment: Please paste the full code. Models.py, forms.py, and views.py

Answer (score 0):

You should raise ValidationError like this:

```
raise ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
```

Here is the full code:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_form = form.save(commit=False)
                mail = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
                raise ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
            else:
                new_form.save()
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:profile'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
            raise new_form.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
```

use "forms" instead of "new_form" the result should look like

```
if User.objects.filter(email=mail).exists():
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
```

Answer (score 0):

I typed as follows and it worked at django-2.0.7:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if self.Meta.model.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like email already exists')
        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('accounts:profile')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```